# Pattern finding for repeating sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, pattern-recognition

Find a pattern for the following sequence.
1,1,3,1,3,5,7,1,3,5,7.....

Let n= the nth number.

Find the nth number of this series

Comment: Sorry, the ellipsis are bugging me a little, is it 1,3,1,3,5,1,3,5,7,1,3,5,7,9,... or 1,3,1,3,5,1,3,5,7,1,3,5,7,11,...? I mean, is just odd numbers or prime numbers?

Comment: @AnaGalois:  $1$ is not prime.  I have my guess what it should be.

Comment: @RossMillikan silly me, you are right, wasn't considering that

Comment: You still have the $7$ in the seventh place.  Do you mean that?  It breaks up the pattern I see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:  It appears the first $7$ should not be there.  Without it, you have one odd number, then two, then three, then four, etc.  The block you are in can be recovered from the triangular numbers.  If you really mean it with both $7$'s I don't see the pattern.

Comment: The lengths of the sequences of odd numbers might be the powers of two...